# using duplicate select to tie to id field

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement that finds the duplicates in my table

```
select Uf_UPC, count(Uf_UPC) as DupCount
from item
group by Uf_UPC
Having (count(Uf_UPC)>1)
```

I want to use the column UF_UPC to tie back to my item table and pull the Item numbers that match the duplicate UPC codes.  Am having no luck.
Thanks,

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Well the duplicate select is working.  But, I can't figure out how to use the values it finds to then bring in the item numbers.

So, basically I want this
itemnum   upc
123              x
234              y
345              x
456              z

I want only the duplicate returns
123     x
345     x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the full results from the item table that have duplicates in sql server?

In that case you should do a subquery with the IN or Exists clause such as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item
WHERE item.uf_upc IN (
SELECT Uf_UPC
FROM item
GROUP by Uf_UPC
HAVING (COUNT(Uf_UPC)>1))
```

Comment: @DragonRider No problem, you should consider reading up on exists and in clauses: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT ItemNumber
FROM item
WHERE Uf_UPC IN (
  select Uf_UPC
  from item
  group by Uf_UPC
  Having (count(*)>1)
)
```

Comment: That worked after I commented out the count(UF_UPC) as dupcount.  I kept getting an error message "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Comment: Yes, I edited that out as soon as I caught it myself.